# consequences of itunes app name being different then xcode project name

Tags: iphone, app-store, naming, xcode4.1

what are the consequences of itunes app name being different then xcode project name?
Will my app not be accepted into the store if they are dfferent?
fyi I already created an app called X on itunes connect and linked it to an xcode project named Y. so is it possible to rename my project in xcode as also X and create a new app on itunes named x and then connect them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many apps have up to 6 different names.  (project, target, product(file name), bundle ID suffix, bundle display (under icon) name, app store name, advertising name, etc.). You can configure these names all individually (I usually do).  No problem as far as Apple is concerned, unless some of them are misleading or a trademark violation or something.

Comment: Can I change the bundle display name from the xcode project info screen? without breaking anything? thank you.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't matter at all. Apple doesn't see your xcode project, just the binary you submit. As long as the binary settings, like the code signing identity are correct, you could name it anything.  Also, I don't recommend renaming your project.  If you do it manually, you will break the project.  And if you use xcode's built in way, you get a kind of weird result (from my experience).

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't matter at all. Project name and even bundle name can be anything. The only thing matter is your bundle id matches app id in the iTunes Connect.